# How can I pass a a modified Command value to the Help() function of Cobra?

Tags: go, go-cobra

I'd like to be able to take the `Long` value of a Command from Cobra and modify it before it's returned to the user when `[program] [command] --help` is called.

While there's ample [documentation](https://github.com/spf13/cobra/blob/main/user_guide.md#defining-your-own-help), Cobra lacks examples to illustrate ways of modifying what's returned from the `Help()` function. As an exmaple, I'd like to include markdown within the `Long` value:

```golang
// other values
Long:    `This [feature](https://www.google.com) blah, blah blah.`
```

And then use a custom parser - which I've already written - that removes the markdown before returning the string to the user:

```golang
// other help information

This feature blah, blah blah.
```

Essentially: can someone provide an example of a function I can pass to `SetHelpFunc()` that will permit me to change this value?